# update multiple fields in SQL

Tags: sql, query

I am trying to update my table in SQL 2012 where the CategoryNumber values should be correspondant for the below name values but it seems that my syntax is wrong.

```
Update mytable
SET mytable.CategoryNumber IN ('02','05','10')
where mytable.name IN ('peter','michael','ralf')
```

Comment: You mention your syntax is wrong.   You don't indicate the reason you believe that to be the case.

Comment: because I got an error when I tried too.

Comment: That was my very subtle hint that you should update the question to include the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` is an operator that defines a set of values, thus it's treated like an unordered list. You cannot do that in the manner you are trying to. I'd suggest doing it one by one:

```
Update mytable
SET mytable.CategoryNumber = '02'
where mytable.name = 'peter';

Update mytable
SET mytable.CategoryNumber = '05'
where mytable.name = 'michael';

Update mytable
SET mytable.CategoryNumber = '10'
where mytable.name = 'ralf';
```

Comment: but actually I have more than 300 values to update.

Comment: You can create an input file where each line has a `CategoryNumber` and a `name`, and iterate over so on each loop iteration the `UPDATE` statement is called with this pair of values.

Comment: @Scorpion99 - You make no mention of that in your question.

Comment: how will I be able to read from this file?

Comment: @Scorpion99 - There are multiple ways.  What have you tried?

Comment: Only the above method